# Current page link not highlighted

Tags: html, css, navigation

I am building a webpage with a fixed side navigation. However the current page will not highlight the desired color. I have a "nav-item" on all of the nav links, and a "nav-item current" on the current page. I beleive the html is fine, and I think the css is fine as well, but I don't get why it won't highlight.

```css
.nav-container {
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  padding-top: 35px;
  
}

.navigation {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  clear: left;
}

.current {
  color: #36d9d3;
}


.nav-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: 200ms color ease;
}


.nav-item:hover {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
        <nav class="navigation">
          
          <a class="nav-item current" href="#">Illustrations</a>
          <a class="nav-item" href="#">Designs</a>
          <a class="nav-item" href="#">Artwork</a>
          <a class="nav-item" href="#">Photography</a>
        
        </nav>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` to your colour for `current` as your style is getting over ridden. For styles defined in external stylesheets, the priority is in the order from bottom to the top for two identical attributes

```css
.nav-container {
  display: block;
  clear: left;
  padding-top: 35px;
}
.navigation {
  width: 75%;
  margin: auto;
  clear: left;
}
.current {
  color: #36d9d3 !important;
}
.nav-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  clear: left;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition: 200ms color ease;
}
.nav-item:hover {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-container">
  <nav class="navigation">

    <a class="nav-item current" href="#">Illustrations</a>
    <a class="nav-item" href="#">Designs</a>
    <a class="nav-item" href="#">Artwork</a>
    <a class="nav-item" href="#">Photography</a>

  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

look this and get an idea.

```js
$(document).on("click", 'ul li', function(){
    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
a:visited {
    color:#000;
}
.nav {
    padding:10px;
    border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;
    border-radius:5px;
    float:left;
}
.nav li {
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    margin:0 10px;
}
.nav li a {
    text-align:center;
    width:55px;
    float:left;
}
.nav li.active {
    background-color:green;
}
.nav li.active a {
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#tab1">Menu 01</a>
  </li>
  <li>|</li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">Menu 02</a>
  </li>
  <li>|</li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Menu 03</a>
  </li>
 
</ul>
```